# How do I recognize the initial white space/spaces in my edit text?

Tags: android, regex, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

I am trying to recognize the initial spaces in my edit text, such that if a user enters `"      "` (any number of spaces) ,it doesnt enable my done button. 
So, far I have this code in placE:

```
String sendString = mSendText.getText().toString();
if(sendString.equals(" ")||sendString.isEmpty()||sendString ==null ){
//do nothing
                }else {
//do my stuff
}
```

The thing is I want the else to work only when I have string with any characters in it as long as it is not JUST ALL whitespace in the beginning.
The code I have works for only 1 whitespace. I want to make it such that no matter how many number of whitespaces exist in the beginning it will remove them or not enable my done button as long as no characters show up.

For example :

```
This should go to the if loop: "      "
This should go to the else loop: "    Hello, it's me"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Match `/^\s*$/` not enabled. Match `/\S/` enabled. So, you get to pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `equalsTo()` to `startsWith()`:

```
String sendString = mSendText.getText().toString();
if( (sendString == null) || (sendString.startsWith(" ")) || (sendString.isEmpty())){
    //do nothing
}else{
    //do my stuff
}
```

Perhaps, if you're interested only in relevant text, you can exclude white spaces in the beginning/ending just using `trim()`

```
String sendString = mSendText.getText().toString().trim();
if(sendString.isEmpty()) {
    //do nothing
}else{
    //do my stuff
}
```

Comment: that works! thanks, but only when I add .trim() and startswith together.

Answer (score 1):

Use `trim()` to delete odd spaces from begin and end of `String`.

```
 String str = new String("   Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com   ");

 System.out.print("Return Value :" );
 System.out.println(Str.trim() );
```

Returns `Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com`

Answer (score 1):

I would remove all spaces then check to see if there is anything in the string after that.

```
String sendString = mSendText.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
if(sendString.isEmpty()){
     // do nothing
}else{
     // do something
}
```